# How to mount second 2TB HDD on running server?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid

I have a server with 2x2TB but only one 2TB disk I can access and mounted.
I am not sure how to mount second 2TB disk (empty) on running server without losing data from first 2TB.

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util
fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors Units =
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util
fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes 255 heads, 63
sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors Units =
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/md3: 1978.9 GB, 1978886193152 bytes 2 heads, 4
sectors/track, 483126512 cylinders, total 3865012096 sectors Units =
sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 21.0 GB, 20970405888 bytes 2 heads, 4 sectors/track,
5119728 cylinders, total 40957824 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 =
512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O
size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk identifier:
0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G  4.2G   14G  23% /
/dev/root        20G  4.2G   14G  23% /
devtmpfs        7.9G  4.0K  7.9G   1% /dev
none            1.6G  284K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
/dev/md3        1.8T  416G  1.3T  25% /home
```

Output fro sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md3

```
/dev/md3:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Wed Jul 13 11:34:23 2016
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1932506048 (1842.98 GiB 1978.89 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1932506048 (1842.98 GiB 1978.89 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Sat Oct 29 12:30:25 2016
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 0fe79156:bfd477c3:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
         Events : 0.15411

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync   /dev/sda3
       1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
```

Comment: Usually, you'd use the `mount` command on a server. Alternatively, [fstab wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) is your friend.

Comment: tried to use `mount` sudo mount /dev/sda /media/home1
mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /media/home1 busy

Comment: There you go. Either it's already mounted, or you need to select another mount point.

Comment: eh why would a SECOND disk be called sda? @Shahbaz would be far more logical for it to be sdb.

Comment: Are you sure they are not both components of the same RAID array(s)? What does `sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md3` say?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify how you intend to use this disk. Additional data or /home? Or part of a RAID? (steeldriver asks a good question).

IF you wish to just use it for additional storage...

If the 2nd hard disk is truly empty, (it's already got a gpt partition table) you'll need to create a partition on it before trying to mount it. Start gparted from the dash. Wait for it to interrogate your disks. Select sdb (which should be your 2nd hard disk). Confirm that there are no existing partitions. Create a NEW partition in EXT4, and name it. Then right-click on the newly created partition and select MOUNT. That should get it going quickly. Then learn how to add it to your /etc/fstab file.

Comment: I want to use as /home
 I already have 2TB in /home